# Standard fields are missing in sandbox

Tags: sandbox

I have one of my customers's sandbox access,but standard fields are missing,because of missing I am unable to installation my package.there is a field in my developer org called dunsNumber,it is missing in sandbox.how can redeem, that field in sandbox.urgent requirement.

Comment: `dunsNumber` isn't a standard field. You'll probably need to deploy it from an Org connected to the Sandbox, to the sandbox.

Comment: but in dev org it is showing as standard one.

Comment: and what are the other custom fields.

Answer (score 2):

> DUNS Number:- The Data Universal Numbering System (D-U-N-S) number is
>   a unique, nine-digit number assigned to every business location in the
>   Dun & Bradstreet database that has a unique, separate, and distinct
>   operation. D-U-N-S numbers are used by industries and organizations
>   around the world as a global standard for business identification and
>   tracking. Maximum size is 9 characters.

**This field is only available to organizations that use Data.com Prospector or Data.com Clean.**

So in your sandbox you don't have data.com. Either you need to install it or remove the reference of this field from your code.

Comment: if i install data.com,then my package will be dependent on data.com.is there any way,can i add the field using configaration